# Async/await axios in external file

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios, vuejs3

I'm trying to understand async/await with axios and external JavaScript file.
This for not include HTTP call in Vue page and reuse it in other components.
When I try this code seem like to work but "const result=await this.login.goLogin(this.password)" the result still undefined.

```
    scr
 |- components
      |-login.vue
 |- service
      |-login.js
```

--> Login.vue method

```
async goLogin(){
            console.log(this.password)
            const result=await this.login.goLogin(this.password)
            console.log('--Res')
            console.log(result)
        },
```

– > login.js function

```
 async goLogin(password){
        //console.log(password)
        await axios.post(appRoute+'user/login',{pwd:password})
                .then(data=>{
                    var user = { token:data.data.results };
                    return user})
                .catch(err=>{
                    return {errorMessage:err.message}})
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first understand the fundamental of how `Async/Await` is different from `Promises`.

Async/Await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

This is an example of a `Promise`:

```
someFunction().then((result)=>{
    /*Your logic*/
}).catch(()=>{
    /*Error handle*/
})
```

This is an example of a `Async/Await`:

```
try{
    let result = await someFunction()
    /*Your logic*/
}catch(err){
    /*Error handle*/
}
```

If you gonna use `Async/Await` with `axios`:

```
let response = await axios.post()
//The program will wait until response got its result.
let user = response.data.results
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning in the chained `.then()` method does not resolve the promise. You can wrap your axios in a `Promise()` object and resolve/reject based on the response:

```
goLogin(password){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(appRoute+'user/login',{ pwd: password })
            .then(data => {
                var user = ;
                resolve({ token: data.data.results });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject({ errorMessage: err.message });
            })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in this manner:
In this way, I can make more complex result and the pending promise in vue side is resolve correctly like above in login.vue

```
--> login.js function
async goLogin(password){
        let result
        await axios.post(appRoute+'user/login',{pwd:password})
                .then(data=>{
                    console.log(data)
                    result = { token: data.data.results }})
                .catch(err=>{
                    result= {errorMessage:err.message}})
        return result
    }
}
```

<sub>*Added on behalf of the question author.*</sub>